# Spring MVC - logged in user and permissions.. how?

Tags: mysql, spring, jsp, spring-mvc

I'm making an online shop (very basic), and here is a thing...I got page where I can log in: `LogIn.jsp`, of course logins and password are in my table in MySQL, my URL of home page is: `http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/home.html`, page of log in `/login.html`, and after log in I want in order to my home page will look something like that: `http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/loggedUserID=1/home.html` and same with rest pages like `/cart.html or /phones.html` I just need in order to in URL page will appear ID of logged in user. How can I do this?

MainController:

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

DBConnection db = new DBConnection();

@RequestMapping(value = "/home.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView HomePage() {

    ModelAndView main = new ModelAndView("Main");

    return main;
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/cart.html", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView cartPage(Model model) throws SQLException,   ClassNotFoundException {

  //something

    ModelAndView cart = new ModelAndView("Cart");
    return cart;

}
```

LoginController:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/login")
public class LoginController {

DBConnection db = new DBConnection();

@RequestMapping(value = "/loginInfo.html", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ModelAndView loginAction(@RequestParam String login,  @RequestParam String password) throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {

    User user = new User();
    user.setLogin(login);
    user.setPassword(password);

    Connection conn = db.getConnect();
    PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT login,  password FROM `onlineshop`.`user` 
    WHERE login LIKE '%"+user.getLogin()+"%' AND password LIKE '%"+user.getPassword()+"%' ");
    ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();

    if (rs.next()){

        ModelAndView success = new ModelAndView("LoginSuccess");
        return success;

    } else {

        ModelAndView loginfailed = new ModelAndView("LoginFailed");
        return loginfailed;

    }

    }
```

and for example reference to home page in LoginSuccess.jsp:

```
<a href="http://localhost:8080/OnlineShop/home.html"
        style="text-decoration: none; color: #000"> HOME </a>
```

Comment: Why do you need the logged in ID in the URL? I see massive potential for abuse/fraud.  You should check out Spring Security.  You can always get the user from thread local

Comment: Because when I add to cart for example phone, In URL will be information for program about which user added to cart phone. But you're probably right, it will be field for fraud. Spring Security.. I was thinking about that, but.. a lot of Spring Security tutorials includes all Maven stuff, but in this project I don't use Maven. Anyway I'll try it, thanks

Comment: You should also look into simple Servlet Filters. This is really how you should be processing requests. In the filter, use the HTTPServletReponse/Request to store a session variable for each user. In the filter, you can decide whether or not someone is logged in.

Comment: This code `conn.prepareStatement("SELECT login,  password FROM onlineshop.user WHERE login LIKE '%"+user.getLogin()+"%' AND password LIKE '%"+user.getPassword()+"%' ");` is vulnerable to SQL-injection. See for details: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Preventing_SQL_Injection_in_Java